# What are the options for dynamically-typed .NET web development at this time?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ironpython, ironruby

What are you options for dynamically-typed .NET web development at this time?

Ruby on Rails with IronRuby?

Django (with a few alterations) and IronPython?

Don't feel like going the [Phalanger](http://www.codeplex.com/Phalanger) route. I'm done with PHP.

I assume there is some way to make ASP.NET MVC more dynamic... but can you fully exploit that in .NET 3.5? There is the work Haack/Lam/Schementi did. [Post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/02/17/aspnetmvc-ironruby-with-filters.aspx) Anyone looked close at this?

What can FubuMVC and MonoRail do with dynamic languages? I'm not very familiar with them.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by dynamic?

Comment: Your mention of ruby/python makes me think you mean dynamic typing of the language, but then you go onto frameworks...

Comment: Yes I mean dynamic typing. I'll fix the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a full implementation of ASP.NET MVC with IronRuby. This has a much more dynamic feel than the regular ASP.NET MVC.

MVC is a pattern about separating responsibilities so I don't see what that has to do with more or less dynamic. From what I get from your post you want the dynamic typing goodness and that stuff is implemented in ironrubymvc.  http://github.com/jschementi/ironrubymvc

You can also use Rails with IronRuby at this moment so that would be another option for you to use, but the dataaccess may need to be revisited though to work with .NET or you need to use one of the .NET OR/M's.

Answer (score 2):

I think the possibilities are:

- Ruby on Rails with IronRuby
- Django and IronPython
- ASP.Net + ASP.Net MVC with IronRuby/IronPython

and if dynamic typing is what you care for, I guess you can wait for C# 4.0 where you can use the dynamic keyword when developing ASP.Net/ASP.Net MVC web apps.

Shay.

Comment: +1. Good thoughts. Just seems like there should be a specific framework for .NET that was more dynamic than MVC. Guess I will wait and see how good the performance of IronRuby gets over the next few months. Don't want to be that guy that goes off and writes yet another framework.

Answer (score 1):

It sounded like Shay was suggested just creating an object of the dynamic type and shoving things in there. I feel like it's better to let IronPython do the dynamic programming stuff, C# do the stuff that really needs it, and use the dynamic type in C# to bridge the gap if you need to go in the other way, calling into dynamic code. Since IronPython already handles calls into C# for you, with C# 4.0 there can be pretty seamless interaction between these two very different worlds.

I love me some Python and Django. I like Django more then I think any other web framework I have messed with. I haven't given the [django patches for IronPython](http://bitbucket.org/jdhardy/django-ipy/) from Jeff Hardy a try though. Could be worth a look to see if that and maybe IronPython 2.6 betas can get you going.

Being able to use Django in a .NET/Mono environment and using C# and the libraries and tools that come with it when needed sounds awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Hardy is working on NWSGI at http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=NWSGI, which is a .Net port of Python WSGI interface.

This opens opportunities to port various Python based web framework (there are kazillion of them)

Answer (score 0):

[IronScheme](http://www.codeplex.com/IronScheme) is currently in beta.  I have no idea if it's any good, but they're building on experience with other Lisp dialects on .NET.